# Can I use id attribute with same value in many posts of blogger?

Tags: html, css

Can I use id attribute with same value in many posts of blogger.

Example like:

**Blogger post 1**

`<div class="panel-heading" id="myPost">some content</div>`

**Blogger post 2**

`<div class="panel-heading" id="myPost">some content</div>`

**Blogger post 3**

`<div class="panel-heading" id="myPost">some content</div>`

**And**

**Blogger post 6000**

`<div class="panel-heading" id="myPost">some content</div>`

That's what I'm doing because css of `myPost` exist in blogger template not exist in posts of blogger.

**CSS in template not in posts of blogger**

`<style> #myPost {background-color: red;} </style>`

I am creating a dictionary blog. I don't want to change css many times in all posts of blogger. I want to change my css in blogger template. , I want to change background color of panel-heading which value of bootstrap 3. When I use class attribute   this code not work of my css (myPost). When I use some content  this code really work and change background color of panel-heading. Bootstrap panel-heading not have own more colours option.

Comment: ID's must only be used once per page. If all your posts are individual pages then *maybe*. Why do you think you need to keep re-using the same ID?

Comment: The ID attribute must be unique. You can use the same class

Comment: What do you mean, per page? I have a blog/website ex. www.example.blogspot.com. in this blog/website, many posts are available. Can i use id attribute with same value in many posts of blog/website.

Comment: NO! you can not

Comment: Your "example" is a **summary** of all your individual posts (which are separate pages). But the real question as I asked is WHY do you need to keep using the same ID?

Comment: Because, I want to change background color of `panel-heading` which value of bootstrap 3. When I use class attribute <div class="panel-heading mypost">  this code not work of my css (myPost). When I use <div class="panel-heading" id="myPost">some content</div>  this code really work and change background color of panel-heading. Bootstrap panel-heading not have own more colours option.

Comment: Hey @KunalTiwalkar - just following up. Was your question answered satisfactorily? If there is more we can help with, please add a comment below any answer, or edit your question to say what else you need to know. Otherwise, please choose a "best answer" (by clicking the checkmark beside the answer) ***to close out the question***. If no answer provided helpful information, please add your own answer and select that as the best answer (to close the question). Remember, too: you can upvote any answers you found helpful (you can also upvote and checkmark the same answer, if desired.) *Thanks!*

Comment: @KunalTiwalkar This question is still open. Please choose a "best answer" (by clicking the checkmark beside the answer) to close out the question. If no answer provided helpful information, please add your own answer and select that as the best answer (to close the question). That would help us out. *Thanks!*

Answer (score 0):

You should not use an ID more than one time on a webpage. If you do, then you cannot target individual elements with that ID - only the first one will work.

Sometimes templates will insert the same ID over and over again, but that is not correct. Some of these templates have a way to unique-ify the ID, some don't.

Usually, you can use classes in much the same way that you use IDs. Classes do not need to be unique. If you are targetting an element via its class using javascript, you need to add `[0]` after the selector because classes return a collection instead of a string (even if there is only one name in the selection, it's still a selection/array)

To change the panel heading of all your posts:

```
.panel-heading{background: palegreen;}
```

If you wish to change each one individually, you can use something like:

```
.panel-heading:nth-child(2){background: palegreen;}
```

You can find a list of css color names [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors.asp).

Comment: No, It does not working your code. Because bootstrap 3 background color already exist in stylesheet

Comment: Try adding !important after the colorname: `.panel-heading{background: palegreen !important;}`

Comment: Yes.  It works. Can I use your same code in many posts of blogger. .panel-heading{background: palegreen !important;}

Comment: You should be able to...  You should also know about CSS specificity. You can try specifying some of the *parent* elements to be more ***specific*** in targetting that div. Eg: `.divAboveThatClassname .divAboveClassname .panel-heading{background:palegreen!important;}`  *(where "divAboveClassname" is not literally those letters, but the classname of the div above)*  See [cssTricks specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

Comment: Use `!important` as a *last resort*, because when you use `!important` it overrides every other specificity - so if you later want to override that, you cannot.  So, first try using additional parent classes to be more specific in your targetting *(see above cssTricks article link)* so that you still leave yourself the option to later use `!important` when it's really... !important

Comment: *(Note: I mentioned using !important as a last resort only so that you know about how it works, and about specificity -- in the real world, use what works. All that matters is (a) that it works, and (b) that you have some idea about the implications of using !important.)*

Comment: Sir, thanks for you help me

Comment: You are very welcome. Please remember to checkmark a correct answer, and to upvote any answer you find particularly helpful.  *Meilleurs voeux* with your project.

Comment: Ok sir, thank you, can I use your Same class attribute with same value in many posts of blogger. .panel-heading {background: palegreen !important;} ........ <div class="panel-heading"></div>

Comment: Sorry, I do note fully understand your question. ***I suggest that you close out this question (checkmark/etc) and ask a new question.*** You can refer to this question (via URL) in the new question. ***If you do that:*** (a) you will have more space to ask a proper question, (b) 1,000 people will read your new question and be able to answer, (c) the question will be answered more quickly (because (b)  ).  Also, every time you close a question (checkmark/upvotes) you get new points. The more questions you ask, the more points you receive. It is how StackOverflow works.

Comment: *(After you create your new question, post a link to it as a reply to this comment and I'll be able to take a look at it - but several people might have already given you the correct answer by then... which is why StackOverflow is so great for asking questions.)*